# Javascript keyup/keydown in .NET WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, keyboard, browser

I have a .NET WebBrowser control that I am using to display some javascript-heavy pages that I've written. The pages use YUI and have been built in a way to be portable.

I have just discovered that while I can capture keypress in javascript, I cannot seem to capture keyup or keydown **in javascript**. This prevents me from hooking ESC, CTRL+A, UP, RIGHT, TAB, for example.

I understand that I can capture the keys in .NET, and that there are 'hacks' for some of these. For instance, Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", .., ..) for CTRL+A. --- By the way, I still cannot get SendKeys.Send("{TAB}") to work for tab ---. I realize that I can use .NET to execute a function that processes the UP arrow, but for portability and best practice reasons, I really don't want to do this.

Can anyone explain why I am unable to capture the keyup/keydown events **in javascript** or suggest a workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into this problem myself with the ATL web browser control (CAxHost).  Not sure how to do this in winforms, but what you need to do is QueryInterface for IOleInPlaceActiveObject off the browser object and then call IOleInPlaceActiveObject::TranslateAccelerator prior to calling TranslateMessage in your message loop.  I think in winforms this means casting the property ActiveXInstance to IOleInPlaceActiveObject (you can probably find a definition of the interface from pinvoke.net)

This should really only be for letting the control do its accelerators (like ctrl-p for print, F5 for refresh etc), but it appears keydown events also key off this call.  If you want to block some of these accelerators, I think you can do so by implementing IDocHostUIHandler::TranslateAccelerator in the Ax host of the browser and checking the Ole command being tested to turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to load this example from yui (h ttp://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/container/keylistener_clean.html) in a winForm Application in which I dropped a WebBrowser Control and everything works fine.
The example uses the keyup event so I think it fits your case.

You might want to check in which mode you WebBrowser control is running http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/03/18/webbrowser-control-rendering-modes-in-ie8.aspx

Marco

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote you a bit of code to show how to capture arrow key press in JavaScript. I have tested this in IE and FireFox so it should be okay...

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" onkeydown="keyPress(event)" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function keyPress(e)
    {
        var textBox = document.getElementById('Text1');

        var keynum;

        if (window.event) // IE
            keynum = e.keyCode;
        if (e.which) // Other browser
            keynum = e.which;

        switch (keynum)
        {
            case 38:
                textBox.value = 'Up Arrow';
                break;
            case 37:
                textBox.value = 'Left Arrow';
                break;
            case 40:
                textBox.value = 'Down Arrow';
                break;
            case 39:
                textBox.value = 'Right Arrrow';
                break;
            default:
                textBox.value = 'Another key';
                break; 
        }
    }
</script>
```

Hope it helps :)